# Problem disabling specific select dropdown fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, disabled-input

Am working on an application whereby I have some cards that have 
select dropdown fields. 
On the Cards I have written a JavaScript logic whereby if the user 
**selected a wife or husband as an option on the any of the cards
select drop down**, any of the other husband or wife dropdown field 
should disable.

The problem is the **other cards do not disable when I select an option from any card**. 
Basically I want when the user **selects wife or husband option 
on any card**, all other husband or wife options on other cards should 
disable instantly.

I get this error in console:

**TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function**

**Markup code**

```
<!-- Card 1 -->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <!-- Gender -->
        <div class="row registerRelationph3">
            <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
            <select class="fm-input otherMenu" id="relation1" required>
                <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
                <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
                <option value="Son"> Son </option>
                <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- END -->

        <!-- DOb -->
        <div class="row">
        <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
        <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
        </div>
        <!-- END dob -->
            <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 1 -->

<!-- Card 2-->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <!-- Gender -->
        <div class="row registerRelationph3">
            <label class="fm-input otherMenu"> Relation :</label>
            <select class="fm-input" id="relation1" required>
                <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
                <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
                <option value="Son"> Son </option>
                <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- END -->

        <!-- DOb -->
        <div class="row">
            <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
            <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
        </div>
        <!-- END dob -->
            <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 2-->

<!-- Card 3-->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <!-- Gender -->
        <div class="row registerRelationph3">
            <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
            <select class="fm-input otherMenu" id="relation1" required>
                <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
                <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
                <option value="Son"> Son </option>
                <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- END -->

        <!-- DOb -->
        <div class="row">
            <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
            <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
        </div>
        <!-- END dob -->
            <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 3-->
```

**Javascript code**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    var selectWife = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Wife"]');
    var selectHusband = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Husband"]');
        selectWife.forEach(function(option) {
            option.disabled = selectedOption === 'Wife';
        });
        selectHusband.forEach(function(option) {
            option.disabled = selectedOption === 'Husband';
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cant add an eventlistener on a list of menus
it must be done for each menu

```
var menus = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu');
for (let menu of menus) {
    menu.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var selectedOption = this.value;
        var selectWife = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Wife"]');
        var selectHusband = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option[value="Husband"]');
        selectWife.forEach(function (option) {
            option.disabled = selectedOption === 'Wife';
        });
        selectHusband.forEach(function (option) {
            option.disabled = selectedOption === 'Husband';
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: ,, Thanks alot for the help,, when I add more cards and select and select husband or wife option, the disabled property is removed on the 1st cards that I selected from

Comment: Firstly you shouldnt use the same ids for inputs in every card.
If my answer solved your problem can you please mark it as correct.